# Too many postgresql versions installed: How to start only a chosen postgresql version or remove the unneeded ones? Needed port is the standard "5432"

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, multiple-versions

##### With many started postgresql services, psql chooses the lowest postgresql version

I have installed two versions of postgresql, `12` and `13` (in an earlier version of this question, these were `9.1` and `9.2`, I change this to be in line with the added output details from the higher versions).

```
sudo service postgresql status
12/main (port 5432): down
13/main (port 5433): down
```

They are located at `/etc/postgresql/12/` and `/etc/postgresql/13/`.

After installing an extension on version `13`:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib postgresql-plpython3-13
```

start the postgresql service:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

which outputs:

```
 * Starting PostgreSQL 12 database server                                                                                                                                                                                             
 * Starting PostgreSQL 13 database server
```

Now let us create the extension in the database, running:

```
sudo su - postgres
```

and then:

```
postgres=# psql
psql (13.4 (Ubuntu 13.4-1.pgdg20.04+1), server 12.7 (Ubuntu 12.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/plpython3u.control": No such file or directory
```

We see that the extension is searched in version `12` although I have installed the `postgresql-python3u` to the directory of version `13`.

##### Aim

I want to use version `13` only, I don't need two different versions, and psql seems to choose the lowest available postgresql version of the started services by default, not the highest which I need.

How to either remove version `12` safely or make `13` the only started (or default) service, also using the standard port `5432` for version `13`?

Comment: I guess you should ask this kind of question on http://superuser.com/ and not here

Comment: I had this problem and it offered the solution. So why should it not be part of the knowledge base? The edit did not lead to a reopening since the `Original close reason(s) were not resolved`, I would like to know how this could be improved, then, to become on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This situation with two clusters in Ubuntu may happen when upgrading to a newer release providing an newer postgresql version.

The automatic upgrade does not remove the old cluster, presumably for fear of erasing valuable data (which is wise because some postgres upgrades may require human work to be complete).

If you know you want to drop it, just run:

```
sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 9.1 main
```

The corresponding data directory will be removed and `service postgresql` will no longer refer to 9.1

At this point the 9.2 cluster will still use the port 5433, which is unpractical.

To switch it to the default port, edit `/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/postgresql.conf` and change the line `port = 5433` to `port = 5432`

Then restart PostgreSQL.

Finally to get rid of the postgresql-9.1 packages see the result of `dpkg -l 'postgresql*9.1*'`

Comment: I can confirm that this has worked when I had PostgreSQL 12 and 13 running on ports `5432` and `5433`.

Answer (score 2):

`psql` fails because none of your postgres is running.
First, you should understand **why** there are 2 different servers, then delete one of them (through `apt-get`, I think), and if necessary reconfigure the other (if you type `sudo service portgresql start`, both of the servers will start, and to connect to 9.2 you must use `psql --port=5433`).
Edit your question to add more informations (Version of Ubuntu, origin of Postgres, etc.)...

Comment: they are running, I've already run 9.2

Comment: So, why your service postgresql status says 'down'?

Comment: because I did it before starting them.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to remove postgres, check the name of the 9.1 package (in Debian is "postgresql-9.1", in Ubuntu may be identical), remove it if possible (dependancy problems may arise). Otherwise, remove 9.2, then remove 9.1 and reinstall 9.2.